# how can I make my image in my page become original size?

Tags: html, css

[here](http://hypergroups.github.io/test/)

How can I make the image become original size under this theme or Resized by scale(width/height=original width/original height))?

Maybe should modify the theme's css?

Comment: You should avoid linking to a live site where the actual code will change. Instead you should copy the relevant portions of the code into your SO question. Even though this requires some extra effort, the process of preparing your question with complete information can sometimes give you a better understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap is including the style `img { max-width: 100%; }`. In most cases, this is what you want… images larger than the viewable area will be scaled to fit. To override, use the value `none`. You should try to target just the image that you want to be the full width by adding a new selector to your stylesheet. In your case, I would use the following CSS:

```
.Output img {
  max-width: none;
}
```

Comment: I've add a max-width:none in the inner css of the html file, seems it doesn't take effect?`<p class="Output" style="
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-left: 66px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 8px;
word-wrap:break-word;
 max-width: none;
">
 <img src="/HTMLFiles\Math\MathNote\Diagonize\Diagonize_15.gif" alt="Diagonize_15.gif" width="1329" height="255" style="vertical-align:middle" />
</p>`

Comment: Maybe I do it wrongly? I should modify the theme's css?

Comment: You're putting the CSS in the HTML… generally speaking you should keep your CSS in a CSS file: [Best Practices: Avoid CSS Inline Styles](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/aa073106.htm). Instead, add the code I put in my answer to the end of your theme's CSS file. (Also, you put the `max-width: none;` on the wrong element in your comment :-p You put it on the `P` tag… it should be on the `IMG` tag. The CSS I provided will correctly target the image.)

Comment: Thanks, put it into the img tag, it works.